# Serialization with Externalizable

Tags: java, serialization

I need to improve serialization performance for my application and now I'm considering implementing `Externalizable` interface. I've read about all serialization pitfalls in `Effective Java` and now I'm a little confused if the state of affairs the same with `Externalizable`?

I know about `Serialization Proxy Pattern` but in my Paticular situation the cost of using such proxies is totally unacceptable.

For example, consider the following class:

```
private static class Test implements Externalizable {
    private int f1;
    private String s;

    public Test(){
        f1 = 0;
        s = "";
        System.out.println("Default constructor invocation");
    }

    public Test(int f1, String s){
        this.f1 = f1;
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(f1);
        out.writeObject(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        f1 = in.readInt();
        s = (String) in.readObject();
    }
}
```

I'd say that it's safe because `Externalizable` explicitly invokes default constructor, so the methods `readExternal` and `writeExternal` operates on   fully constructed objects rather then using extra-linguistic mechanism in case of `Serializable`.

But since, I've not used Externalizable in practice so far I need some advice. I've also read that `readExternal` and `writeExternal` should be thread safe. What is that suppose to mean in this case? I mean I have to be lock-free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Externalizable` classes avoid many of the pitfalls of standard `Serializable` classes, yes. Your class implementation looks fine, at first glance.

Thread-safe here means that your code should work properly if multiple threads call `writeExternal` and `readExternal` simultaneously (with a different object for each thread). Again, your class implementation doesn't have a problem here.

Comment: Good point about read/writeExternal. You won't get two thread calling readExternal on the same object, but you could have two calls to this method on different objects.  You could have two threads calling writeExternal on the same object. + 1

Comment: According to this I'd say that Serializable is now considered as a legacy. It seems to me that it's almost always better to implement Externalizable rather than Serializable.

Answer (score 4):

> I've also read that readExternal and writeExternal should be thread safe. What is that suppose to mean in this case?

If you are writing an object updated by another thread, you have to be sure you are writing something which is correct.

Similarly, if you are reading a new object and you pass it to another thread, you have to ensure visibility.

Note: as long as you pass this object via a thread safe queue or reference you shouldn't have a problem.